# How does remote switches learning system work?

Tags: remote-control, algorithm

I've been searching like crazy for none success so now im asking you guys.

You know these electric control switches that you can turn on and off with a radio wave remote control? Usually the remote is programmed of sending 433.92Mhz radio waves.

1. How does the signal look like to the receivers/switches?
2. How do the remote give each receiver an ID.
3. If you know how the whole "self-learning" system works, I would love to hear it.

here is a picture of a remote with switches.
[image: Switches]

Comment: Answer to first question: No, I don't know this "electric control switch that you can turn on and off with a radio wave remote control".  Without a real description, datasheet, or maybe even just a picture *it is difficult to tell what is being asked here*.

Comment: Added a link to a picture

Comment: It seems pretty general as a product, different manufacturers can use different protocols, how can you determine what? Maybe you want to design something similar? Maybe it's better if you start from what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation of the programming function of the switches is described on the [Nexa web site](http://www.nexa.se/):

> The operation is simple, the receivers are provided with a small "mode" button that you press, then take the remote control and select the button you want to use for that specific receiver, press it and the "VIPPS", then the transmitter and receiver communicate with each other.

There are 67 million potential addresses, so selecting an unique ID is simple. Each controlled device apparently supports up to 6 IDs and responds to whichever of them is pressed.

Regarding how the signal looks to the receivers built into the sockets / switches: Most likely a digital signal encoded on a 433.92 MHz carrier. When a matching ID code is received by a switch, it acts upon it as designed.

For more information, at least the non-proprietary parts of how the device works, what you need is a Swedish translator perhaps, but not an electronics design site: [Manuals and documentation](http://www.nexa.se/Manualer-Dokumentation.htm) are provided on the web site.

The aspects not provided in the documentation are conceivably not public information.

Comment: Thanks I have actually been looking into this site as i am swedish. I have missed that the switches also has a button.

Comment: What i also want to know is how the signal looks like, is it a special header with an ID in it then a message or how is it?

Comment: @Furedal That would be speculative: It depends on the protocol used by the devices, which I haven't found documentation for. There are far too many common, popular protocols for such digital signaling, and then the variations individual manufacturers create to remain proprietary. You might have to use some form of RF protocol sniffer to gain further insight.